# Ограничение на количество просмотра материала по IP

Tags: drupal

Необходимо реализовать ограничение на просмотр материалов по количеству просмотров с одного IP адреса.
После того как пользователь зайдёт определённое количество раз в текущий день он уже не сможет зайти на любую страницу принадлежащую к данному типу материала. Вместо этого у него появится другая страница с информацией.
С помощью каких модулей можно реализовать подобный функционал?
Возможно готовые примеры реализации, или предложения по реализации будут полезными.

Comment: Вы в курсе, что с одном и того же IP адреса в интернет могут выходить тысячи человек?

Comment: Да, в курсе. Но вот такая возможность необходима.

Comment: Блокировка ресурсов по IP – бессмысленна, беспощадна и архаична. Она давно изжила себя для *информационных* ресурсов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно писали в комментариях к вопросу - задача достаточно редкая из-за того, что так никто не делает, поэтому найти готовый модуль не получится.

**Drupal 6**

- https://www.drupal.org/project/accessctypebyip - можно взять и конвертировать на 7ку. Как конвертировать модуль можно загулить или начать 
  с https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7

**Drupal 7**

- https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_ip - не совсем то, что нужно, но наверняка реализованы основные "блоки".

Answer (score 1):

Решение задачи приведено в самом ответе. Причем, на уровне семантики.

Если абстрагироваться от средств разработки (под вопросом тэг Drupal) и сфокусироваться исключительно на моделировании функциональности, имеем следующее:

- В первой таблице БД храним IP-адреса "заходов" и счетчик посещений;
- Во второй таблице храним категории/типы материалов (это явное условие задачи);
- Ну и, наконец, третью таблицу используем для создания отношений "многие-ко-многим".

Все что останется сделать – реализовать счетчик и блокировать доступ, перенаправляя на "заглушку".